# Why isn't `:escape => false` supported by all ActionView tag generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I need to generate a hidden input element with `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper#hidden_field_tag`, but I don't want the input value to be escaped.

What I would like to do is this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('hidden_input', sanitize('actual_input_value'), :escape => false) %>
```

But this just renders an HTML input with `escape="false"` as an attribute.

I can get around this by avoiding the `FormTagHelper#hidden_field_tag` method and using `TagHelper#tag` directly:

```
<%= tag('input', { :name => 'hidden_input', :value => sanitize('actual_input_value'), :type => 'hidden', }, false, false).html_safe %>
```

But this is more verbose and less readable, particularly given that I have several usages of `#hidden_field_tag` very close to this tag generation.

Is my desired functionality absent by design, or is this a feature that could be added into ActionPack?  It *is* present for at least one other helper method (see `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper#text_area_tag`)